# Contiki on Apple IIe without Uthernet card

Tags: apple-ii, internet

Can I run Contiki on my Apple IIe without an Uthernet card?  For example, I was thinking that I could run my Raspberry Pi to emulate a network card through the serial port as a null modem.  Any examples of people doing this sort of thing would be appreciated.

(Yes, I know about [A2Cloud](http://appleii.ivanx.com/prnumber6/category/a2cloud/) but that doesn't put the TCP/IP stack on A2, it just makes the A2 basically a dumb terminal which isn't so interesting to me.)

Update: Looks like someone did the [same basic thing](http://jmp.no/blog/cheap-overkill-amiga-network-adapter) on an Amiga, but not with Contiki.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I reached out to [Oliver Schmidt](https://github.com/oliverschmidt), maintainer of Contiki for Apple 2 (among other things), and he suggested the following:

> You can't "emulate" an Uthernet card with an RPi but you can -
>   generally - use the RPi to get online with Contiki.
>
> *** Warning ***
>
> I haven't tried what I describe below myself. And I have a report that
>   it doesn't work reliably. And it's quite some effort. Nevertheless...
>
> Instead of using an Ethernet card Contiki can be built to use a
>   SuperSerialCard to connect to a SLIP server. There's no pre-built
>   Contiki for SLIP, you have to build it yourself.
>
> Read
>   https://github.com/contiki-os/contiki/blob/master/cpu/6502/README.md,
>   especially
>
> "The cpu/6502/ directory is used for targeting 6502-based machines
>   using the cc65 compiler http://cc65.github.io/cc65/."
>
> and
>
> ```
> WITH_SLIP Default: 0 Purpose: Use SLIP (based on RS232 driver coming
> with cc65) instead of Ethernet.
> ```
>
> additionally read
>   https://github.com/contiki-os/contiki/blob/master/platform/apple2enh/README.md,
>   especially
>
> "The 'disk' make goal requires AppleCommander 1.3.5 or later. It is
>   available at http://applecommander.sourceforge.net/."
>
> You can either build the individual Contiki programs using e.e.g
>   https://github.com/contiki-os/contiki/blob/master/examples/webbrowser-80col/Makefile
>   or build them all using
>   https://github.com/contiki-os/contiki/blob/master/tools/6502/Makefile
>
> Getting the RPi ready is supposed to be easy, e.g.
>   https://harizanov.com/2013/03/tcpip-over-rfm12b-and-raspberry-pi-as-gateway/
>   says that something like
>
> ```
> sudo modprobe slip  
> sudo slattach -L -s 38400 -p slip /dev/ttyAMA0 
> sudo ifconfig sl0 192.168.5.1 dstaddr 192.168.5.2
> ```
>
> is enough.
>
> Please note that I don't know more about this then what I wrote above.
>
> Good luck. Oliver

I will update this with my progress doing so, and try to post the rebuilt Contiki binaries somewhere as well.  Thanks to Oliver for his assistance.

**Update:** I was having trouble with the compilation, so Oliver was kind enough to compile for me and send along.  [Here are the compiled binaries](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1IyYqirYW92M2UFKKNJMr6lhAtbLm6Zc9/view?usp=sharing) if you are interested.